# how to create a loop and save the data array variable individually?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I write a helper function `read_xyT` to read all .csv files in a directory and output them into a pandas DataFrame. Since there are lots for such directories and I want to save them into individual variables (or maybe some better solutions?)

what I do now is

```
path = r'./data/T-600s'
df33 = read_xyT(path,33)
df34 = read_xyT(path,34)
df35 = read_xyT(path,35)
df36 = read_xyT(path,36)
...
```

There is in total 60 folders... I wonder if there is a smarter way to do it more efficiently? i.e.

```
subdirectoynames = np.arange(34,50) # the helper function take 'path' as input
variablenames = alistforfilenames
for v,f in (variablenames, subdirectorynames):
  dfxx = read_xyT(path,yy)
```

then I'll have the saved individual variables such as `df37`, `df38`, `df39`, ...

Or is there a better way to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not dictionary? `d = {'df33': read_xyT(path,33), 'df34': read_xyT(path,34)}`. You can create it with a loop.

Comment: @Guy thanks for the hint, before I just know there is something called "dictionary", now I kind of understand what it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension:

`df_dict = {f'df{idx}': read_xyT(path, idx) for idx in subdirectorynames}`

This creates a dictionary where you can access the dataframes using e.g. `df_dict['df33']`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I am kind of new to python, or coding in general. I did it manually because I failed to find a solution by googling, but good that I decided to ask :) and learned a new method "dictionary" :D

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Best of luck on your journey!